# Are jsp standard actions used anymore?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jspinclude

This is a quick question for all of you writing jsps in production. Do you use jsp standard actions and why? What are maybe some of common use cases?

I ask because there are so many taglibs out there that seem to be so much more capable and I am not sure if considering standard actions for any task is worth is anymore.

Thanks.

Edit: By standard actions I mean the fol:

jsp:useBean

jsp:getProperty

jsp:setProperty

jsp:include

jsp:forward

jsp:param

jsp:plugin

jsp:attribute

jsp:body

jsp:element

jsp:text

Comment: Should we assume you mean JSTL when you say standard actions?

Answer (score 1):

Still using `jsp:include`, but not often.  Not used the rest at all since adopting EL, JSTL and Tiles.

With Tiles, we don't *need* to use `jsp:include`, but there's no reason to use `tiles:insert` just for the sake of it, I tend to only use `tiles:insert` when referencing definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Only the `<jsp:include>` (and `<jsp:param>` as child) is useful. The remnant is ultimately useless when using a proper MVC design or framework. Maybe the `<jsp:plugin>` is useful for applets, but since some years there exist an applet deployer JavaScript file which makes it superfluous.

Some JSP purists may opt that `<jsp:useBean>` is also useful in order to trigger IDE autocompletion of bean properties in EL. But it is not required per se when using the MVC approach.

#### Related questions:

- [Design patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)